# Hibernate no longer an independent product

Tags: nhibernate, jboss

What happened to Hibernate.org?  I get redirected to jboss.org and then once on that site I can not find it.  Does this mean that hibernate is no longer an independent project - it is now a component of jboss.

Comment: Watch out, someone asked the same question earlier and got down-voted and closed as "not programming related."  May want to make this community wiki, or suffer some rep loss... :)

Comment: You are correct, how does one do that?

Comment: Edit the question and check "community wiki" check box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has always been part of JBoss. They were the ones that created Hibernate.

Now, if you are looking for [NHIBERNATE](http://www.nhibernate.org), that's a completely different product and URL.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NHibernate) is the WIKI entry, and [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate) is the sourceforge download site.

Comment: http://www.nhibernate.org/ also seems to be down. http://nhforge.org/ works though.

Comment: hibernate has always been associated with JBoss, but it has also always had its own site and distro.  It seems that there is a major shift going on.  hibernate.org used to be its own site, but now it redirects to the jboss.org site.

Comment: @Andy: Yes, correct. But it has been a JBoss' project for a long time now, since if I recall correctly, it was JBoss who hired Hibernate's lead developer.

Comment: Well, it's an open source project so it doesn't "belong" to JBoss, but they certainly seem to be the major (only?) sponsor for the project. Personally, I think it just annoying that they just redirected to jboss.org instead of a "hey we're changing things" page.

Comment: This is what I had expected, but I have not been able to find it on the jboss.org site

Answer (score 0):

http://www.jboss.com/products/hibernate/

On the Products menu, it's "JBoss Hibernate".

But you're right--old links to documentation are broken, e.g.
http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/context/ThreadLocalSessionContext.html

takes you to a generic jboss.org top level page.  Hopefully they'll fix it.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate works as well.

Comment: Looks like they might be fixing it now.  I just checked hibernate.org again, and they have a maintenance image up now.  whew